# how to edit a read-only file using a script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I have a read-only file data.txt. I have one user guest_user, and I have an executable shell script myScript.sh. 
The requirement is guest_user cannot edit the read_only file directly, or by vi/vim editor. Nor can he chmod the data.txt file. 
But he should be able to edit this data.txt using myScript.sh. 
So what should be coded inside this shell script to make this editing of data.txt work?

Comment: Look at how `crontab`, `vipw`, and `visudo` approach the problem. Basically, give the user a temporary copy, then install it to the  correct location using a privileged program.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a file that is read-only can't be edited. There are two options - either read the file, edit the contents of it, and save it to a new file, or somehow modify the privileges of the user or the file to make it so it's not read-only (e.g. with `sudo`, `chmod`, etc.). Which of these you are trying to accomplish is not clear...

Comment: @twalberg. You are right, can't be done other than any other way you suggested. I was asked this in an interview, which I wasnt able to answer correctly (according to the interviewer). So was curious to know what would be the solution that he was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If the guest user have administrative privilege (can use `sudo`) then you can do that with `sudo vi` or `sudo vim`, and if doesn't then it's impossible without having any prior write permission.

Comment: I was asked this in an interview in Amazon. I too said I would use sudo in the script. Interviewer said I am a guest user not a superuser. I wont be possessing a superuser credentials. He hinted there is a keyword we need to add to the shell script for this to work.

Comment: It's impossible at least without some kind of hacking... I presume

Comment: @aiman If you really can do that, then you can say that Linux is hacked and proved to be totally insecure... bypassing permission without having any permission to do so will certainly prove Linux to be the most insecure OS there is, and with just one keyword? lol... must be a joke or something....

Comment: i guess you are correct. I too feel the same. I dont know what answer was the interviewer expecting.

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround, if you know the guest user password. Just add this in your shell script.

```
echo "guest-user-password" | sudo su -
nano /path/to/data.txt
```

Now, you can edit the file and save it. It will still be `read-only` file.